# How to show information about an entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem. After clicking on the "create order" button, the user is redirected to the URL: "localhost:8080/currentorder/{id}" After visiting this URL, the user should see order.text.

Attempts to solve: In the DAO, I create a method that, by the ID passed from the controller, looks for an order in HQL:

```
public List show(Long id) {
        Transaction tx = null;
        try (Session session = BogPomogi.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Order where id = :id");
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            List result =  query.getResultList();

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

But as you understand, after that, the timelif could not display anything (I mean order.getStatus()) Now I still think that I need to search the database and return an object, but how? help me please
My code:

**Controller**

```
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String createOrder (@ModelAttribute("order") Orderdao orderdao, String text, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        orderdao.createOrder(text);
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id", orderdao.checkLastOrder());
        return "redirect:/currentorders/{id}";
    }

    @GetMapping("/currentorders/{id}")
    public String showOrder (@PathVariable("id") Long id, Orderdao orderdao, Model model, Order order){
    model.addAttribute("currentOrder", orderdao.show(id));
    return "order";
    }
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order implements Serializable{



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String text;

    private String customer;

    private int status;



    public Order(String text, String customer, int status) {
        this.text = text;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.status = status;
    }




    public Order(String customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }


    public Order(){

    }
    //Getters and setters
```

**Method**:

```
     public Order show(Long id) {
        Transaction tx = null;
        try (Session session = BogPomogi.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Order where id = :id");
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            List result = (List) query.getSingleResult();

            session.getTransaction().commit();
         
            return (Order) session.save(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am missing your code for `orderDao.create`, but usually you would have a service class (annotated with Springs `@Service` annotation), which is injected to the controller and which is called to create the entity. You can make this service method return the ID of the just created entity. It could hence be something like `public Long createOrder(OrderDao orderDao)`. Inside there, after calling `repository.save(entity)`, the entity will already have the ID set (try to verify yourself with debugger: Set a breakpoint to the line before you `save` the entity and check the ID is null, then go one step forward and see that after `save`, the ID is set).

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

```
    public Order show(Long id) {
    Transaction tx = null;
    try (Session session = BogPomogi.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select text from Order  where id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        String result = (String) query.getSingleResult();

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return new Order(result, "adsfreger", 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).